# Single instance of UserControl shared between XAMLS

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Does anyone know how to create and maintain a single instance of a UserControl and share it across multiple XAML pages?

My scenario is creating a background update checker. The issue is I'd like to have instances of my UserControls receive progress updates from my background thread (TAP pattern) using IProgress or something similar. Now I could solve this by registering to the background thread using an Observer pattern or something. But it would be even easier if I could create a shared instance of the UserControl I'm targeting which is similar to how iOS works.

Any other ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Not quite sure but i think you can use a DI container like `Autofac` and registering that `UserControl` as a single instance

Comment: @visc  If I am getting it right, you have a base view which you want to be able to access from which ever page you want at all time? or is it, that you want to have a userControl that can be poped up whenever you want from any page or service in your code? or is it something else?

Comment: @AdityaSharma I have pages or "views" that include a UserControl in their XAML that is common to all of the pages of that type. i.e. not all pages will have this UserControl, just ones of a certain type. That being said, I would like to have the handle/instance to that UserControl remain constant across all of the Pages. So a thread operating on it's UI elements can reference the same controller. No need for an observer pattern.

Comment: A `Control` can't have more than one parent. Trying to put the same instance in multiple places isn't going to work out well. A better solution is to have multiple `UserControl` instances accessing the same instance of their view model.

Answer (score 1):

After understanding from the comments, I guess I have a clear understanding, if my answer indicates otherwise feel free to use the comments section and I'll answer accordingly. Getting right to it,

---

You can create a singleton static instance of the `userControl` instead of making the whole `userControl` `static`. Say for example you have a user control named `"UserDataControl"`. Declare a static variable of it in the code behind:

```
 public static UserDataControl Instance { get; set; }
```

and it's constructor would look something like below:

```
public UserDataControl()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Instance = this;
}
```

Now, because you want to add the `userControl` into multiple pages using the same instance, you can't add the control via `XAML`. So using c#, in the `onLoaded` function add the userControl to the grid or Container wish. For eg: on the mainPage you want to add the control to the `rootLayout` `Grid` below is the code for the `onLoaded` event:

```
 Loaded += (s, e) =>
 {
      if (UserControls.UserDataControl.Instance == null)
         UserControls.UserDataControl.Instance = new UserControls.UserDataControl();

       rootLayout.Children.Add(UserControls.UserDataControl.Instance);
 };
```

**Please Note:** Check if the instance is null, because if you're initializing for the first time it'll be null.

Now while navigating make sure you `override` the `OnNavigatingFrom` event on all pages where you're using the `Singleton Instance` to avoid `Element is already the child of another Element` exception. below is the code from the above example:

```
protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    //remove the user control as a child as leaving it as a child will throw you an
    //error "No installed components were detected.  Element is already the child of another element."
if (rootLayout.Children.Contains(UserControls.UserDataControl.Instance))
            rootLayout.Children.Remove(UserControls.UserDataControl.Instance);
        base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
}
```

---

That's it. For a complete sample code you can download the demo source code from one drive.

**Github LINK:** [SharedUserControlSample](https://github.com/ImCarrot/SharedUserControlDemo-Stack)

Comment: I suggest you actually initialize the Singleton and reference it in the constructor of the UserControl. Also consider storing it as a Platform::WeakReference. Lastly as Aditya said, make sure to null check!

Comment: @visc has the issue been resolved by this answer? if yes could you please mark my answer as correct (or even upvote it, if you liked the approach) so that this thread will be closed?